# Read comma-separated file which also have comma within a column

Tags: r, csv

I have a file where the separator between columns is comma (`,`). However, comma may also occur *within* columns, i.e. the 'Notes' column:

```
Id,Notes,Other_ID
100,This text looks good,1000
101,This text,have,comma,2000
```

I tried to read the csv:

```
r <- read.csv("test.csv", sep = ",")
```

As a result, I received it as :

```
Id.Notes.GUID
100,This text is good,1000
102,This text,have,comma,2000
```

which is incorrect, as I would like to have the output as

```
Id       Notes                  GUID
100      This text is good      1000
102      This text,have,comma  2000
```

Goal is to receive the data intact with the columns irrespective of comma present within a column and shouldn't work like a delimiter.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

**1) read.pattern** `read.pattern` will read the fields according to the provided regular expression. For reproducibility we have used Lines in the Note below but if the data is in a file replace `text=Lines` with something like `"myfile.csv"` .

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = "^(.*?),(.*),(.*)$", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   Id                Notes Other_ID
1 100 This text looks good     1000
2 101 This text,have,comma     2000
```

**2) Base R** Read the data into a character vector and replace the first and last comma on each line with some character that does not otherwise occur such as semicolon.  Then read that.

```
L.raw <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
L.semi <- sub(",(.*),", ";\\1;", L.raw)
read.table(text = L.semi, header = TRUE, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   Id                Notes Other_ID
1 100 This text looks good     1000
2 101 This text,have,comma     2000
```

**3) gawk** If you have a very large input file then it would likely be faster to do as much as possible outside of R.  Using `gawk` we have the following.  (On Windows install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) if you don't already have `gawk` and also make sure it is on your path or else refer to it using the entire pathname.)  In the `BEGIN` block `first` is the number of commas to replace before the field with commas and `last` is the number of commas to replace after the field with commas.  In this case the field with commas is the second of 3 fields so first = last = 1.

```
# generate test input

Lines <- "Id,Notes,Other_ID
100,This text looks good, 1000
101,This text,have,comma,2000"

cat(Lines, file = "ambuj.dat")

# gawk program to replace commas
ambuj.awk <- '
BEGIN { first = 1; last = 1 }
{ 
  nc = gsub(/,/, ",") # number of commas
  for(i = nc; i > nc-last; i--) $0 = gensub(/,/, ";", i) # replace last last commas
  for(i = 0; i < first; i++) sub(/,/, ";") # replace first first commas 
  print
}'
cat(ambuj.awk, file = "ambuj.awk")

read.csv(pipe("gawk -f ambuj.awk ambuj.dat"), sep = ";", quote = "",
 comment.char = "")
```

Also you could set `colClasses=` to speed it up a bit more.

### Note

```
Lines <- "Id,Notes,Other_ID
100,This text looks good, 1000
101,This text,have,comma,2000"
```

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm, quick question: do we have to define (.*) as many times as number of columns present in data set?

Comment: The pattern in `read.pattern` must correspond to the data so if the data has a different number of columns or the columns are in a different order then the pattern will have to be modified appropriately.

Comment: One more query I have, the number of comma(,) in that text column are not fixed, at some rows there are 2 and at some other there are 7. How can we determine the maximum number of commas and prevent them to split the text into several parts.

Comment: The number of commas shouldn't matter.  The `^(.*?),` captures everything up to the first comma, the first `(.*),` captures everything after the first comma until the last comma no matter how many commas that field contains and the `(.*)$` at the end captures the last field.

Comment: So do I have to enter (.*) as many times as number of text columns present in the database?Or does defining (.*) once will do the task? Because I have 8 columns with 3 numeric columns in beginning, 4th column as text with comma, 5th column blank,6th column number,7th column text and 8th column text.The only column have commas in text is 5th one for which I wrote the code as: ^(*.?),(*.?),(*.?),(.*),(.*),(*.?),(.*),(.*)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For 5 columns we want `^(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$` except for the column with commas omit the ? .

Comment: reading the file consists of 5million rows and it is running from last 2 hours.Is there anything that can be done to speed up the process?

Comment: will it also handle the comma s in text column? as there is not any semi colon present in the file.can you share a simplified syntax for it which will be really halpful considering the file format as I mentioned earlier.Thank You.

Comment: Have generalized and fixed awk code.   `first` and `last` in the `gawk` BEGIN block must be set appropriately.